# get full path folder that is select in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have same problem  in web application 
i use( PHP-HTML-javscript ).

I want select folder and  it get full path that is folder 
for backup data 
EXP:
" when user enter backup.php he go to select folder that is folder move backup data mysql"

I find for that ,but not get full path

```
      <input type="file" name="dirctory"  multiple webkitdirectory  />
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get local path of an upload file. It's a security feature in all modern browsers.

You will get directory path with the string `C:\fakepath\` in order to prevent inappropriate information disclosure. So trying to obtain the path is worse then useless in newer browsers - you'll actually get a fake one instead.